# How do you disable "Swipe down to close" on the Modal component in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using the core [React Native Modal component](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html). Within the modal content I have a `Done` button.

Pressing `Done`is the only way we want users to close the modal. But the Modal component allows swiping down from the top of the screen to close.

How do you turn off "swipe to close"?

Comment: Never encountered dismiss on swipe for Modal but might be related - try setting modal prop `onRequestClose={()=>{}}`

Comment: As written in the docs `Note: If you need more control over how to present modals over the rest of your app, then consider using a top-level Navigator.`, you might want to make a navigator and define the `transitionType` as `modal` if you're using `react-navigation`. Right now there is nothing to stop the swiping action unless it is wrapped in some component.

Comment: Are you using the React-Navigation package?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To answer @Nikolai in the comments,  I am using React Navigation.

I didn't realize the gesture settings from the navigator also controls the gestures of the react native modal.

Turning off gestures solved my problem.

```
const HomeScreenContainer = StackNavigator(
  {
    HomeScreen: { screen: Screens.HomeScreen },
    PostScreen: { screen: Screens.PostScreen },
    CameraScreen: { screen: Screens.CameraScreen },
    CameraRollScreen: { screen: Screens.CameraRollScreen },
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: {
      gestureEnabled: false,
    },
  },
);
```

Comment: Note that this will also work if You have `mode: 'modal'` property in `StackNavigator` configuration. Just make sure that line `gesturesEnabled: false` is inside the navigator where the modal screen is.

Comment: It's very confusing that react-navigation says `gestureEnabled` instead of `gesturesEnabled`.

Comment: Probably at the time of writing this answer it was `gesturesEnabled`. In the latest version of `react-navigation` it's actually `gestureEnabled`.

Answer (score 12):

Struggled with it a bit too. Here is what worked for me:

If you have root navigator as modal and inside it another stacked navigator for which you want to disable gestures, then put this inside root navigator for the stacked navigator, worked for me in v2.12 iOS

    `navigationOptions: {
        gesturesEnabled: false,
      },`

here's full code:

```
const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    LoginNavigator: {
      screen: LoginNavigator,
      navigationOptions: {
        gesturesEnabled: false,
      },
    },
    ModerationNavigator: {
      screen: ModerationNavigator,
    },
    WalletNavigator: {
      screen: WalletNavigator,
    },
    FloatingNavigator: {
      screen: FloatingNavigator,
    },
    UIKitNavigator: {
      screen: UIKitNavigator,
    },
    MainMapViewScreen: {
      screen: MainMapViewScreen,
    },
    FullscreenPhotoScreen: {
      screen: FullscreenPhotoScreen,
    },
  },
  {
    mode: 'modal',
    initialRouteName: 'MainMapViewScreen',
    headerMode: 'none',
    header: null,
  },
);
```

Answer (score 11):

Since React Navigation Version 5.x, they have changed it to `gestureEnabled` instead of `gesturesEnabled` *(without the 's)* for both [StackNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#gestureenabled) and [DrawerNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#gestureenabled)

Sample usage:

```
<Stack.Navigator mode="modal" screenOptions={{ gestureEnabled: false }}>
    <Stack.Screen name="HomeNav" component={HomeNavigator} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Comment: Best comment EVER 'gestureEnabled instead of gesturesEnabled'

Comment: Is it possible to temporarily disable this, e.g. only when the user has unsaved changes in a modal? Like having a callback or event handler that can optionally call e.preventDefault()

Answer (score 7):

In addition to @GollyJer's answer, if you want to disable the swipe gesture for a single Modal you can also do this:

```
const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
    ModalScreen: {
      screen: ModalScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        gesturesEnabled: false
      },
    }
}
```